# Removing \n\r between double quotes - PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do I remove \n and \r only when found between double quotes?

I basically need the syntax to the `preg_replace`.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I've tried some tips that people give in Stackoverflow... Well, im in a bit hurry, and it's a really fast question..

Comment: @nunong21: The rules don't change just because _nunong21_ is in a hurry.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean? `'abc "\ndef\r" \n\rghi` -> `abd "def" \n\rghi'"` or `'abc "def" rghi'`?

Comment: Provide more context. Depending on the complexity of the grammar (what your string may or may not look like), finding any string which only occurs between specific other strings is quite a complex problem and may require a real parser.

Comment: OK, the text is something like this ' texx text text; " tex text text \n text " text text text '

Comment: May quotes be nested within quotes? May quotes be escaped somehow?

Comment: nop, the \n needs to be between double quotes :)

Comment: So `"foo \" bar \n \""` or some such variation is not possible? What about `"foo" \n "bar"`?

Comment: This question is in the wrong place. What tips have you tried? What worked and what hasn't?

Comment: ' texx text text; " tex text text \n text " text text text \n' I need to remove the \n from inside the "" only. Not the one in the end :)

Comment: i've tried about 10 variations of preg_replace, and none worked, if any of them worked i could see it, but like i don't, i asked a single question...

Comment: look up preg_replace. match everything inbetween quotes that is a newline and remove it.

Comment: Well, too much downvoted, sorry for the question, and thanks to those who tried to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace( '/["]*(\n).*["]/', '', $str );
```

Hows that for replacing \n between "qoutemarks"?

Comment: Yeah, it work :) Thanks for not giving up :)